# React Native WebView Audio Control in Android Lock Screen and Notification Bar

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native

I have developed a WebView application using React Native that contains audio tracks. I want to control these audios through the lock screen and notification bar. While there are no issues on the iOS side, I'm experiencing problems with the Android version. I'm considering using a different library for controlling the audio in the background. Can you recommend a solution or library that would help solve the issue on the Android side?

App.tsx

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import {ActivityIndicator, View, Text, BackHandler} from 'react-native';
import TrackPlayer, {Capability} from 'react-native-track-player';

export default function App() {
  const webViewRef = useRef<WebView | null>(null);
  const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = useState('https://www.example.com');
  const [allUrlsTried, setAllUrlsTried] = useState(false);
  const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false);
  const urlsToTry = ['https://www.example.com', 'https://example.com'];
  const artworkImage = require('./assets/images/example.png');
  const playIcon = require('./assets/images/play_icon.png');

  useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide();
    setupPlayer();

    const listeners = [
      TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-play' as any, () =>
        TrackPlayer.play(),
      ),
      TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-pause' as any, () =>
        TrackPlayer.pause(),
      ),
      TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-next' as any, () =>
        TrackPlayer.skipToNext(),
      ),
      TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-previous' as any, () =>
        TrackPlayer.skipToPrevious(),
      ),
    ];

    return () => {
      // Cleaning up the listeners when the component is unmounted
      listeners.forEach(listener => listener.remove());
    };
  }, []);

  const setupPlayer = async () => {
    await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
    TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
      capabilities: [
        Capability.Play,
        Capability.Pause,
        Capability.SkipToNext,
        Capability.SkipToPrevious,
        Capability.Stop,
      ],
      compactCapabilities: [Capability.Play, Capability.Pause, Capability.Stop],
      notificationCapabilities: [
        Capability.Play,
        Capability.Pause,
        Capability.SkipToNext,
        Capability.SkipToPrevious,
        Capability.Stop,
      ],
    });
  };

  const playTrack = async (url: string, title: string) => {
    await TrackPlayer.reset();
    await TrackPlayer.add({
      id: 'trackId',
      url: url,
      title: title,
      artist: 'example',
      artwork: artworkImage,
    });
    TrackPlayer.play();
  };

  const handlePlayback = async (data: any) => {
    if (data.isPlaying) {
      playTrack(data.url, data.title);
    } else {
      TrackPlayer.pause();
    }
  };

  const handleLoadingError = () => {
    const failedUrlIndex = urlsToTry.indexOf(currentUrl);
    if (failedUrlIndex < urlsToTry.length - 1) {
      setCurrentUrl(urlsToTry[failedUrlIndex + 1]);
    } else {
      setAllUrlsTried(true);
    }
  };

  if (allUrlsTried) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18, textAlign: 'center'}}>
          Sorry, the page is unavailable.
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#131313'}}>
      <WebView
        ref={webViewRef}
        source={{uri: currentUrl}}
        startInLoadingState={true}
        renderLoading={() => (
          <View
            style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#f30543" />
          </View>
        )}
        onError={handleLoadingError}
        onHttpError={handleLoadingError}
        onMessage={event => {
          try {
            const message = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);
            console.log('message-------------', message);
            if (message.type == 'play') {
              console.log(' ------------- play -------------');
              handlePlayback({
                url: message.url,
                title: message.title,
                isPlaying: true,
              });
            } 
            else {
              console.log(' ------------- pause -------------');
              handlePlayback({
                url: message.url,
                title: message.title,
                isPlaying: false,
              });
            }
          } catch (e) {
            console.error('Failed to parse message from WebView:', e);
          }
        }}
        injectedJavaScript={`
        (function () {
          let lastSentURL = '';
          let action = ''; 
          
          const attachAudioEventListeners = (audioElement) => {
              // Attach play event
              audioElement.addEventListener('play', () => {
                  sendAudioDetails(audioElement, 'play');
              });
      
              // Attach pause event
              audioElement.addEventListener('pause', () => {
                  sendAudioDetails(audioElement, 'pause');
              });
          }
      
          const sendAudioDetails = (audioElement, playbackStatus) => {
              if (audioElement && audioElement.src) {
                  window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
                      type: playbackStatus,
                      url: audioElement.src,
                      title: audioElement.getAttribute('title') || 'Unknown Title'
                  }));
              }
          };
      
          const checkAndAttachListeners = () => {
            const audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');
            if (audioElement && !audioElement.__listenersAttached) {
                audioElement.__listenersAttached = true;
                attachAudioEventListeners(audioElement);
            }
        };
      
          const observer = new MutationObserver(checkAndAttachListeners);
          observer.observe(document, {
              attributes: true,
              childList: true,
              characterData: true,
              subtree: true,
          });
      
      })();
      true;    
      `}
        userAgent="Chrome/58.0.3029.110"
        containerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#131313'}}
        style={{marginTop: 5}}
        originWhitelist={['https://*']}
        allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        scalesPageToFit={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        incognito={true}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

    <application
      android:name="com.example.example.com.MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      
      <activity
        android:name="com.example.example.com.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        
      </activity>
      <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedIntentReceiver" android:exported="false">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
      <service android:name=".LockedNotificationListenerService"
          android:label="@string/service_name"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
          android:exported="true"> 
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
          </intent-filter>
      </service>
      <service android:name="com.guichaguri.trackplayer.service.MusicService"  android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.guichaguri.trackplayer.service.MusicService.ACTION_PLAYBACK_EVENT"/>
              <action android:name="com.guichaguri.trackplayer.service.MusicService.ACTION_PLAYBACK_STATE"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
      <receiver android:name="com.guichaguri.trackplayer.module.MusicModule$NotificationReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.guichaguri.trackplayer.notification.BUTTON_PLAY"/>
            <action android:name="com.guichaguri.trackplayer.notification.BUTTON_PAUSE"/>
            <action android:name="com.guichaguri.trackplayer.notification.BUTTON_STOP"/>
            <action android:name="com.guichaguri.trackplayer.notification.BUTTON_NEXT"/>
            <action android:name="com.guichaguri.trackplayer.notification.BUTTON_PREVIOUS"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
      
    </application>
</manifest>
```